# High memory usage in my theme, how to find out why?

Tags: memory

I'm experiencing a problem of high memory usage in my custom WordPress Theme, and I'm trying to find out what's causing it.

I'm already using Query Monitor to explore the situation, but I can't see anything wrong there. No queries that require a long time, (almost) no duplicates, no errors, nothing.
I just see a high memory usage (53,701 kB, 41.0% of 131,072 kB server limit, 131.1% of 40,960 kB WordPress limit), and hear my MacBook Pro fan become very loud when I load the site.
Also, no errors in my error log.

So my question here is: what could I do to find out what's causing this memory usage? Are there ways to know exactly which parts of my code are causing the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried a process of elimination? More advanced tooling such as xdebug or profiling tools might provide memory footprint over time giving you clues as to when it uses memory not just how much it's using at its peak. Inevitably, the tooling you need to figure this out is going to be less WordPress oriented and more generic PHP tooling, you may be severely limiting your options by restricting the question to just WordPress.

Comment: Haven't used it myself and not sure if it can be used on any instance, but [the Sail Profiler looks really promising](https://konstantin.blog/2021/wordpress-performance-profiling-with-sail-cli/) in that aspect.

Comment: Is 53,701kB even that high? In my experience you can hit that pretty easily if you're using something like ACF or WooCommerce.